# export multiple datasets from a .hdf5 to csv in python

Tags: python

I have a hdf5 file containing 4 datasets and each dataset has 3 columns. dtype is int64. I am trying to export it into a .txt or .csv file and I would like to have each dataset in a separate file and each file would have 3 columns. I tried this command in python: 
[here is small example of inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMGTO.png)

```
with open('test.txt','wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,s1,fmt='%s')
```

but the output is a .txt file with many lists and there is no column. also different datasets are not separated! here is small example of out put I want to get, of course for one dataset which would be in a separated file.

```
s1 s2 s3 
4 6 8
5 7 8
7 4 6
```

Do you advice on how to do that?

Comment: Give a small example of the content of `s1`.

Comment: question is updated with a pic. please click on link. in the input 0, 1 and 2 represent s1, s2 and s3

Comment: That's not very helpful. I'm interested in the way `s1` is obtained: how did you extract the hdf5 dataset and how is it as a numpy datatype? Try not to include links to images: they will rarely stay available for years. Instead, add the data (or a subset of it) to your question in a text format.
While you're at it, can you add an example (the first 20 characters or so) of the content of `test.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the free tool HDFql (http://www.hdfql.com) in Python to solve this issue using the following code snippet:

```
# import HDFql module (make sure it can be found by the Python interpreter)
import HDFql

# use (i.e. open) HDF file named "example.h5"
HDFql.execute("USE FILE example.h5")

# write datasets dataset1, dataset2, dataset3 and dataset4 into files file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv and file4.csv
HDFql.execute("SELECT FROM dataset1 INTO FILE file1.csv SPLIT 3")
HDFql.execute("SELECT FROM dataset2 INTO FILE file2.csv SPLIT 3")
HDFql.execute("SELECT FROM dataset3 INTO FILE file3.csv SPLIT 3")
HDFql.execute("SELECT FROM dataset4 INTO FILE file4.csv SPLIT 3")
```

The result of executing this code would be four files named `file1.csv`, `file2.csv`, `file3.csv` and `file4.csv`
each of which will contain the data stored in dataset `dataset1`, `dataset2`, `dataset3` and `dataset4` respectively.

For every three elements (in your case, three 64 bit numbers) written in the file, a new line is also written (hence the keyword `SPLIT 3`), and each element is separated by a comma. If you need a different separator, use the keyword `SEPARATOR` (e.g. `SELECT FROM dataset1 INTO FILE file1.csv SEPARATOR * SPLIT 3`).